# If $\int f(x)dx =g(x)$ then $\int f^{-1}(x)dx $ is equal to

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function

> If $\int f(x)dx =g(x)$ then $\int f^{-1}(x)dx $ is equal to
>
> (1) $g^{-1}(x)$
>
> (2) $xf^{-1}(x)-g(f^{-1}(x))$
>
> (3) $xf^{-1}(x)-g^{-1}(x)$
>
> (4) $f^{-1}(x)$

My approach is as follows:
Let $f(x)=y$, therefore $f^{-1}(y)=x$, $\int f^{-1}(f(x))dx =g(f(x))$

On differentiating we get $x=g'(f(x))f'(x)$

After this step, I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Why not try an example to see whether any of those formulas work? $\int x^2\,dx=x^3/3+C, $\int\sqrt x\,dx=(2/3)x^{3/2}+C$, do any of the formulas work in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignoring the constant of integration the answer is (2):$$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=\int yf'(y)dy=yf(y)-\int f(y)dy$$ (where I have used integration by parts). Hence  $$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=f^{-1}(x)x-g(y)=xf^{-1}(x)-g(f^{-1}(x))$$.

Answer (score 12):

There's a nice visual computation of the antiderivative of an inverse function: $$F(x) := \int_0^x f^{-1}(t) dt$$ is an antiderivative for $f^{-1}(x)$, and for $x = a$, $F(a)$ is equal to the green area in the picture below<sup>†</sup>:
[image: area under the curve of the inverse function]

If we could figure out the blue area, we would be set, because

\begin{align*}
\text{ (green area) } &= \text{ (rectangle area) } - \text{ (blue area) } \\
F(a) &= af^{-1}(a) - \text{ (blue area) }.\
\end{align*}

But if we reflect this picture across the line $y = x$, we see the blue area is just the antiderivative of $f$, namely $g(x) := \int_0^x f(t) dt$, evaluated at $f^{-1}(a)$:

[image: antiderivative of the original function]

So we get $$\text{ (blue area) } = g(f^{-1}(a)),$$

and plugging this in, we get that $F(a)$ is equal to the second of the four choices:

\begin{align*}
F(a) &= af^{-1}(a) - \text{ (blue area) } \\
 &= af^{-1}(a) - g(f^{-1}(a)). \
\end{align*}

---

<sup>† To make the picture look nice, we assumed $f(0) = f^{-1}(0) = 0$ without loss of generality.</sup>

Comment: Very nice explaination

Answer (score 5):

Given $y=f(x) \implies x=f^{-1}(y)$
Then $$\int f^{-1}(x) dx=  \int f^{-1}(y) dy= \int x dy= \int x \frac{dy}{dx} dx=\int xf'(x) dx $$ $$=xf(x)-\int f(x)dx=xf(x)-g(x)+C.$$ Lastly, we have done integration by parts.

Comment: It’s a very clear answer. You have made every step so clear.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers have already given you the finest methods of solving the problem. I want to say that as you’re given the options for the integral $\int f^{-1} (x) dx$, it would be a nice thing to differentiate the options to see if we get $f^{-1}(x)$ (it should follow from [The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) ).

Let’s try the first option:
$$
If ~~~~ \int f^{-1}(x) dx = g^{-1} (x) \\
then~~~~~ f^{-1} (x)= \frac{d}{dx} g^{-1} (x) \\
f^{-1} (x)= \left(
                   \frac{d~g(x)}{dx} \right)^{-1}\\
f^{-1} (x)= \frac{1}{f(x)}$$ (in the third step I once again used the FTC for the function$f(x)$) the last equality is not true in general, therefore this option is not valid.

Let’s try the second option:
$$
If~~~~ \int f^{-1}(x) dx = xf^{-1} (x) - g\left( f^{-1}(x)\right) \\
then~~~~ f^{-1}(x)= \frac{d}{dx} \left[xf^{-1} (x) - g\left( f^{-1}(x)\right) \right] \\
f^{-1} (x)= f^{-1}(x) + x \frac{d~f^{-1}(x)}{dx} - f\left(f^{-1} (x)\right) \frac{d~f^{-1}(x)}{dx}\\
f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(x) $$
Hence, the second option is correct.

Hope it adds something to this thread!